# Ansible docker_container command failing with no output

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm having an issue here with the ansible docker_container command.

```
- name: Start Docker
  docker_container:
    name: postgres
    image: "centos/postgresql-94-centos7"
    state: started
    recreate: yes
    pull: yes
    env:
      POSTGRESQL_USER: "test"
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: "test"
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: "test"
      POSTGRESQL_MAX_CONNECTIONS: 100
      POSTGRESQL_SHARED_BUFFERS: 32M
    exposed_ports:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
```

When this command runs, it boots the container, but the container immediately exits with some output that I can't see because ansible doesn't print sys out for that for some reason.

Here's an example of some output that is printed when the container refuses to boot (due to incorrect config):

```
$ sudo docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRESQL_USER="test" -p 5432:5432 centos/postgresql-94-centos7
You must either specify the following environment variables:
  POSTGRESQL_USER (regex: '^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$')
  POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD (regex: '^[a-zA-Z0-9_~!@#$%^&*()-=<>,.?;:|]+$')
  POSTGRESQL_DATABASE (regex: '^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$')
Or the following environment variable:
  POSTGRESQL_ADMIN_PASSWORD (regex: '^[a-zA-Z0-9_~!@#$%^&*()-=<>,.?;:|]+$')
Or both.
Optional settings:
  POSTGRESQL_MAX_CONNECTIONS (default: 100)
  POSTGRESQL_MAX_PREPARED_TRANSACTIONS (default: 0)
  POSTGRESQL_SHARED_BUFFERS (default: 32MB)

For more information see /usr/share/container-scripts/postgresql/README.md
within the container or visit https://github.com/openshift/postgresql.
```

This is the output that I do not see when I run it from ansible, it just says its up (success) and then I check docker ps and its not up because presumably it immediately exited. What's more weird is that I can get this to work just fine with the same configuration passed to the ansible command module, but with the docker_container maybe its not passing the env correctly? I'm really not sure because I can't even get the error output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check

```
docker ps -a
```

to see if ansible managed to at least create the container. If it did, check

```
docker logs postgres
```

Hopefully that should give you a clue where it's failing. If you're confused with that maybe you can post some of the (redacted) logs to show where it's failing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `registered.ansible_facts.docker_container.Output`, where `registered` is the fact you used to register your `docker_container` play with.

More information here: https://wordpress.com/post/carlosonunez.wordpress.com/1440